# How To Create New Content Type Programmatically in Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, module, drupal-7, content-type

I'm building a module (`my_module`) in Drupal 7.

It has some functionality and also will create new content type.

In *my_module.install* I implemented the `hook_install` (`my_module_install`).

Can I use more one implementation of `hook_install` to create new content type (`my_cck_install`) in this module?

If (yes), how should I do this?

Else: have I do this in another module? :-)

Answer (score 10):

You can't use more than one implementation of `hook_install` in the same module; in PHP you can't have 2 function with the same name which rules this out.

You would just need to add your new content type in the same `hook_install` anyway (have a look at how the standard installation profile does it at /profiles/standard/standard.install). This is how I always add new content types from the install file (using the example of a testimonials module):

```
function testimonial_install() {
  // Make sure a testimonial content type doesn't already exist
  if (!in_array('testimonial', node_type_get_names())) {
    $type = array(
      'type' => 'testimonial',
      'name' => st('Testimonial'),
      'base' => 'node_content',
      'custom' => 1,
      'modified' => 1,
      'locked' => 0,
      'title_label' => 'Customer / Client Name'
    );

    $type = node_type_set_defaults($type);
    node_type_save($type);
    node_add_body_field($type);
  }
}
```

Comment: I see 'testimonial' only in database, what have i add to see 'testimonial' in admin/structure/types?

Comment: Clear Drupal's cache, that should do it. Try to visit `admin/structure/types/testimonial` directly to make sure your code has actually been run

Comment: I'm sorry for my mistake, it doesn't work at all. Shouldn't I use the hook_node_info()?

Comment: It totally depends. If you want to handle the functionality of the content type yourself then yes, you want to create what's known as a "node module" (using `hook_node_info()` etc). If you're just looking to create a content type with no special processing then the way above is much easier. Did you make sure to uninstall and re-install the module when you put the new code in?

Comment: No, I didn't it yet. Can you give me a direction what to do? Please.

Comment: The easiest way...install the [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel), then visit `mysite.com/devel/reinstall`. From there tick the checkbox next to your module and hit 'Reinstall' at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 3):

The following code will create a content type called "Event" with a machine name of 'event' and a title field -

```
//CREATE NEW CONTENT TYPE
function orderform_node_info() {
  return array(
    'event' => array(
    'name' => t('Event'),
    'base' => 'event',
    'description' => t('A event content type'),
    'has_title' => TRUE
    ),
  );
}


function event_form($node,$form_state) {
  $form['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#title' => t('event Title'),
    '#default_value' => !empty($node->title) ? $node->title : '',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#weight' => -5
  );
  return $form;
}
//END CONTENT TYPE
```

you should place it in your `.module` file... if you want do add additional fields to it, let me know and I'll patch you up with the code... good luck!

Comment: I was able to get this far but I'm wondering how to store and access the form data http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79729/trivial-example-of-a-module-that-creates-a-content-type

Answer (score 0):

```
     /**
     * Implements hook_node_info()
     */
    function mymodule_node_info() {
        return array(
            'news' => array(
                'name' => t('News'),
                'base' => 'news',
                'description' => t('You can add  News here'),
                'has_title' => TRUE,
                'title_label' => t('News title')
             )
        );
    }

 /**
 * Implement hook_form()
 */
function mymodule_form($node, $form_state) {
    return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
}
```

Add the implementation to mymodule.install is as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_install().
 */
function mymodule_install() {
    node_types_rebuild();
    $types = node_type_get_types();|
      node_add_body_field($types['news']);
}
```

You can get a detailed description with code from [here](http://www.mujuonly.com/2015/09/programmatically-creating-new-content.html)

Answer (score 0):

/*
 * Implementation in hook node info in **.Module file**
 */

```
function test_node_info() {
return array(
  'product' => array(
    'name' => t('Product'),
    'base' => 'product',
    'description' => t('Product Title'),
  )
);
```

}

/**
 * Implement hook_form()
 */

```
function product_form($node, $form_state) {
return node_content_form($node, $form_state);
```

}
/**
 * Implements hook_install() in **.install file**.
 */

```
function test_install() {
node_types_rebuild();
$types = node_type_get_types();
node_add_body_field($types['product']);
//New way to implement to add fields in your content type
foreach (_test_installed_fields() as $field) {
    field_create_field($field);
}
foreach (_test_installed_instances() as $fieldinstance) {
    $fieldinstance['entity_type'] = 'node';
    $fieldinstance['bundle'] = 'product';
    field_create_instance($fieldinstance);
}
```

}

/*
 * Define your fields
 */

```
function _test_installed_fields() {
$t = get_t();
return array(
  'product_title123' => array(
    'field_name' => 'product_title123',
    'label' => $t('Product Title'),
    'type' => 'text'
  ),
  'description123' => array(
    'field_name' => 'description123',
    'label' => $t('Description'),
    'type' => 'text'
  ),

);
```

}

/*
 * Define your instance of fields
 */

```
function _test_installed_instances() {
$t = get_t();
return array(
  'product_title123' => array(
    'field_name' => 'product_title123',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => $t('Product Title'),
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'text_textfield'
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'example_node_list' => array(
        'label' => $t('Product Title'),
        'type' => 'text'
      )
    )
  ),
  'description123' => array(
    'field_name' => 'description123',
    'type' => 'text',
    'label' => $t('Description'),
    'widget' => array(
      'type' => 'text_textarea_with_summary'
    ),
    'display' => array(
      'example_node_list' => array(
        'label' => $t('Description'),
        'type' => 'text'
      )
    )
  ),

);
```

}

/**
 * Implements hook_uninstall().
 */

```
function test_uninstall() {
$ournewtype = 'product';
$sql = 'SELECT nid FROM {node} n WHERE n.type = :type';
$result = db_query($sql, array(':type' => $ournewtype));
$nodeids = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
    $nodeids[] = $row->nid;
}
node_delete_multiple($nodeids);
node_type_delete($ournewtype);
```

}

That's it.